# Generic "append to file if not exists" function in Bash

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to write a util function in a bash script that can take a multi-line string and append it to the supplied file if it does not already exist.

This works fine using `grep` if the pattern does not contain `\n`.

```
if grep -qF "$1" $2
then
    return 1
else
    echo "$1" >> $2
fi
```

Example usage

```
append 'sometext\nthat spans\n\tmutliple lines' ~/textfile.txt
```

I am on MacOS btw which has presented some problems with some of the solutions I've seen posted elsewhere being very linux specific. I'd also like to avoid installing any other tools to achieve this if possible.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are small enough to slurp into a Bash variable (you should be OK up to a megabyte or so on a modern system), and don't contain NUL (ASCII 0) characters, then this should work:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' contents <"$2"

if [[ "$contents" == *"$1"* ]]; then
    return 1
else
    printf '%s\n' "$1" >>"$2"
fi
```

- In practice, the speed of Bash's built-in pattern matching might be more of a limitation than ability to slurp the file contents.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I replaced `echo` with `printf`.

Comment: This almost works for me except the `\n\t` gets rendered as a string by `printf` unless I use `%b`. If I use that though the pattern matching doesn't detect it so it repeatedly appends.

Comment: @madcapnmckay, if your string (`$1`) has escapes that need to be expanded before appending to the file then they need to be expanded before doing the comparing and appending.  One way to do it is: `IFS= read -r -d '' contents <"$2"; printf -v str '%b' "$1"; if [[ "$contents" == *"$str"* ]]; then return 1; else printf '%s\n' "$str" >>"$2"; fi`

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  n = 0 # length of pattern in lines
  m = 0 # number of matching lines
}
NR == FNR {
  pat[n++] = $0
  next
}
{
  if ($0 == pat[m])
    m++
  else if (m > 0 && $0 == pat[0])
    m = 1
  else
    m = 0
}
m == n {
  exit
}
END {
  if (m < n) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      print pat[i] >>FILENAME
  }
}
' - "$2" <<EOF
$1
EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

*if necessary, one would need to properly escape any metacharacters inside* `FS | OFS` :

> ```
> jot 7 9 | 
>
> {m,g,n}awk 'BEGIN {    FS =  OFS = "11\n12\n13\n"
>                    _^= RS = (ORS = "") "^$"      } _<NF || ++NF'
> ```

```
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

> ```
> jot 7 -2 | (... awk stuff ...)
> ```

```
-2
-1
0
1
2
3
4
11
12
13
```